# Convert data type from character to date

Tags: r, date, type-conversion

I am failing to convert a data type `chatacter`into a `date`.
This is an example how my data looks like:

| title | date |
| --- | --- |
| this is a title | 2022:02:15 0231 |
| this in another title | 2022:10:06 0800 |

I have tried to convert the date, that is at the moment a `character` type into a `date` type and remove the last 4 numbers:

```
df$date <- as.Date(sub("\\s\\d{4}$", "", df$date), format = "%Y:%m:%d", origin = "1970:01:01")
```

Unfortunately this gives me a `double`. So I have tried also to do this:

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
```

Still getting a `double`and not a `date`format.
What do I do wrong?

Comment: When I run your code and do `str(df)` I see `date` show up as a `Date` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not the best at coding but this would be my solution.

```
df <- data.frame(title = c("this is a title",
                           "this is another title"),
                 date = c("2022:02:15 0231",
                          "2022:10:06 0800"))

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(gsub(":", "-", str_sub(date, 1, 10))))

class(df2$date)
```

I worked it through the following way:

```
a <- "2022:02:15 0231"
a

b <- str_sub(a, 1, 10)
b

c <- gsub(":", "-", b)
c

d <- as.Date(c)
d
```